# Skybox is not visible through transparent objects

Tags: c++, opengl, blending

I learn opengl here: https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps
Did skybox. If you draw it first, then everything is fine. However, to reduce the number of pixels for its output, I try to draw it last. But when you look at the skybox through transparent objects, it is not displayed. If you draw skybox before transparent objects, then they are not displayed. How to fix it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJACL.jpg)

Comment: Actually, you already told the solution: draw the skybox first. Why? For the transparent pixels depth values are written (as well as for the non-transparent). These depth values prevent drawing of pixels for skybox (which are probably much further away). Some helpful links: [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) and [Transparency, Translucency, and Blending](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Transparency is not order independent. You cannot draw something "behind" a already drawn surface. You will have to draw the skybox (at least) before you draw your transparent objects.

Note, that you also have to order your transparent objects back to front if it should be possible to correctly see through multiple of them.